# Angularjs filter - Compare multiple checkboxes boolean with JSON list, display union

Tags: json, angularjs, checkbox, union

In the view there are three checkboxes that change the states of the three values of $scope.colorChoice.

I would like to write a function that compares every true color to the corresponding color in the JSON list. 
If a person has at least one color in its array that has been checked true,
the persons name should be displayed.

How can i write such a function?

So far I've come so far:

**JSON list:**

```
  [
    {
    "name": "kevin",
    "colors": ["red, green"]
    },
    {
    "name": "hans",
    "colors": ["green"]
    },
    {
    "name": "jolene",
    "colors": ["red, blue"]
    },
    {
    "name": "peter",
    "colors": ["blue"]
    }
  ]
```

**Checkboxes:**

```
<label ng-repeat="(item,enabled) in colorChoice">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="colorChoice[item]">
</label>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.colorChoice = {
    red: false,
    green: false,
    blue: false
};
```

***For example:***

```
    $scope.colorChoice = {
    red: true,
    green: false,
    blue: true
};
```

...would display:
Kevin, Jolene, Peter

Thanks for your help!

Vin

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to look into is the angular-checklist-model,

http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

That won't solve your problem as I see you are already handling what it would handle for you. I find it very clean to use for a purpose like yours though.

With that colorChoice object you could do something like this whether you use angular-checklist-model or not though:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat='person in people | filter: colorFilter'>{{person.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Controller Filter Function

```
$scope.colorFilter = function(person) {
    for (var i = 0; i < person.colors.length; i++) {
        var color = person.colors[i];
        if ($scope.colorChoice[color] == true)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

I like to use the angular filters like so with functions that return true or false. They can be extremely versatile for situations like this.
[angular filter guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kyle - The checklist-model looks very interesting.

I've come up with the following solution now:

*First a little helper function to filter out all activated checkboxes:*

```
$scope.colorChoiceTrue = function () {
        var result = [];
        for (var key in $scope.colorChoice) {
            if ($scope.colorChoice[key] === true) {
                result.push(key);
            };
        };
        return result;
    }
```

*Another helper function to search a string in an array:*

```
$scope.searchStringInArray = function (str, strArray) {
        for (var j = 0; j < strArray.length; j++) {
            if (strArray[j].match(str)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

*Finally, this function returns every person who has at least one color matching the colorChoice:*

```
$scope.peopleSelected = function () {
    var result = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.people, function (entry, key) {
        if ($scope.searchStringInArray(entry.color, $scope.colorChoiceTrue())) {
            result.push(entry.name);
        };
    });
    return result;
};
```